# Calculating the frequency of a TRUE event in a 24 hour period (R)

Tags: r, events, time, frequency

I have a data set below:

```
   YEAR  STATION     DAT                 AbovePeak cumSum
  <chr> <fct>       <dttm>              <lgl>      <int>
 1 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-01 01:00:00 FALSE          0
 2 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-01 06:00:00 FALSE          0
 3 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-01 07:00:00 TRUE           1
 4 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-01 08:00:00 FALSE          1
 5 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-01 09:00:00 FALSE          1
 6 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-01 10:00:00 FALSE          1
 7 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-01 11:00:00 FALSE          1
 8 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-01 13:00:00 FALSE          1
 9 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-06 03:00:00 FALSE          1
10 1993  COOP:047821 1993-01-06 07:00:00 FALSE          1
```

Using a previous function, I created the AbovePeak column to indicate whether or not a value was above or below a preset Peak value. 
However, now I am looking to count the frequency of `TRUE` events in a 24 hour window. Then I will use this number of qualifying days  with at `>= 1 TRUE` Event and divide it over the total number of days of measurements. Ideally, I would then group it by `YEAR` such as:

```
 YEAR  numAbove percAbove numBelow percBelow cumPerc
<chr>    <int>     <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1993         4    0.0808     4944     0.919  0.0808
2 1994         0    0.         4948     1.00   0.0808
3 1995         0    0.         4948     1.00   0.0808
4 1996         3    0.0606     4945     0.939  0.141 
5 1997         1    0.0202     4947     0.980  0.162
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a 24-hour window as a single calendar day, the solution may be quite easily obtained with `dplyr()`, e.g. like this

```
library("dplyr")
library("lubridate")
# group by days & calculate a number of threshold exceedance for each day
res_by_days <- x %>% group_by(YEAR, as_date(DAT)) %>% summarise(DayAbovePeak = any(AbovePeak),
    numBelowDaily = sum(!AbovePeak))
```

The column `numBelowDaily` was added for further calculation of the annual number of the measurements resulted in a below-threshold result. If I understand your idea properly, this value should be written to the `numBelow` column of the final result grouped by years:

```
# group by years & calculate yearly values
res_by_years <- res_by_days %>% group_by(YEAR) %>% summarise(percAbove = sum(DayAbovePeak)/n(),
        numBelow = sum(numBelowDaily), percBelow = 1 - sum(DayAbovePeak)/n())
# calculate a cumulative percentage in a separate column
res <- res_by_years %>% mutate(cumPerc = cumsum(percAbove))
```